# Multiple pages authentication and user details retrieval - razor page

Tags: .net, authentication, dependency-injection, razor-pages, asp.net-core-middleware

After deploying the app in the dev server - IIS, I am facing this issue.

There is no login page.
The user name is displayed in the `layout`, so that it is displayed for the entire site regardless of the page the user is in.
The user is authorized with an internal library and few checks (trying to implement authorization in a middleware) - but this is not yet implemented.

Works correctly:

1. When I access the site in the following way,

- domain/homepage - shows my id
- domain/otherpage - shows my id

2. When my co-worker access the site in the following way,

- domain/homepage - shows co-worker's id
- domain/otherpage - shows co-worker's id

DOES NOT Work correctly:

1. When I access the page directly domain/otherpage (without accessing the homepage/index page) - shows my id
2. And then my co-worker access the page directly, domain/otherpage
   (without access the homepage/index page) - shows my id

I do not know if this is session related issue.
The homepage/index page is where I am getting the user id, which is then access through the entire site.

I understand that getting user information in the other page will solve the issue but I do not know if this is the right way of doing this.
Am I required to get the user id in every page of a site?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Such as how you deploy it, how to access, how to verify and so on. Also, you can authenticate every page to make sure only authenticated users can access it, that's no problem.

Comment: How are you authenticating users?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Chen Sorry about the lack of clarity in question, i have updated it now. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: @Mike Brind, there is an internal library that the org uses to authenticate users. So, i have some db checks and the checks in the library that i use to authenticate the user.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without knowing exactly how the internal library works or how it has been applied. It certainly seems that your authentication is not being scoped correctly to the user. That could be a result of a bug in the internal library or incorrect application of it. Or something else entirely.

Comment: @MikeBrind right now, i have not implement the check with the internal library because i am unable to get the correct id (without any authorization check) in the page. if i am able to fix this then i can take it to next step of implement some checks.

I have edited the question.

Comment: You really need to show the relevant code if you want some help.